# New site on IIS keeps asking for windows username password

Tags: c#, iis

I am setting up my .net (C#) site on IIS on a new server running windows standard 2019. I have deployed this site on 2 different servers (different windows versions) previously without an issue. I have assigned it a domain name. When browsing to this domain name, it keeps showing a windows prompt for username and password. I have enabled anonymous authentication with IUSR account, which I have added to the IIS_USERS group. I have given this group read & execute permissions on my site folder in wwwroot. I cannot figure out what the problem is. Anybody have any ideas?

Thanks

[image: Authentication]

[image]

Comment: If you are using disk space it is best to use a network drive rather than disk on the server.  A http connection to a IIS is using GUEST privilege's and does not have access to the resources on the IIS.   So any disk space you need should be on a network drive where users can access.

Comment: Try setting Anonymous Authentication to user `IUSR`

Comment: Can you show the web.config and the section of applicationhost config about the security of this website? It seems that windows authentication or basic authentication has been enabled and ask for credentials from user.

Comment: @schlonzo I already have anonymous authentication set to user IUSR, as I wrote in the initial post.  Bruce, I will edit my post with screenshots

Comment: You didn't assign enough [permissions](https://serverfault.com/a/171773) to the folder? You are being [redirected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55605540/11683) to a different server? You have a problem with [Windows Admin Center](https://serverfault.com/q/1025390)?

Comment: @GSerg the folder definitely has all the correct permissions. I have compared it to the other servers I've deployed on. It is not redirecting anywhere. It is on this server and I get the same request for username/password calling localhost or the ip address. Please clarify what you mean by a problem with Windows admin Center

Comment: Click the link?

Comment: @GSerg sorry didn't notice it was a link. Thing is that I am not using 443 here. I am using port 80 (http) at least for now. Trying to get it running before adding ssl etc